# Can you store the base64 encoded text that you get when encoding a file (txt) in a byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, http, base64

I want to make an http request using a stream (because I think there is no other way) but I can only send a byte array using streams. I want to send a file by encoding it in Base64 then sending the encoded base64 code so I can decode it later. So far I can easily encode it using

```
byte[] contentBytes = loadFile(txt);
byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(contentBytes);
String encodedContentString = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

But as one can see I get a string. Can I turn it into a byte array not or can I encode the file into a byte array directly? Maybe I used it wrong but I am pretty sure I can't just use `encodedContentStrin.getBytes()`

Comment: Isn't `encoded` a byte array?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the encoded data as a byte array after

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(contentBytes);
```

There is no need to convert it to a `String`.

Comment: Oh yeah but, you know, when I run this and then print it out, in this example it prints out `[B@17d99928` and I am fairly certain that this is not text that is base64 encoded

Comment: You should have included that in your question.  This is one of the most-asked questions on Stack Overflow. Please see the duplicate target.